# Adding tangent lines and dots for tangent points to numerically plotted curves

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

This is a question related to Michael E2's answer to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287287/solving-implicit-function-numerically-and-plotting-the-solution-against-a-parame/287300?noredirect=1#comment716928_287300).

First, using this code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n = 1;
eqns[i_,b_] = {D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == 
D[1 - e, 
  e] ((-(((a (-1 + e) - i - (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
           e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(
            b - 1)))) w))) - (-(((a (-1 + e - i) - (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
           e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))), 
0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, w >= 0, 0 <= b <= 1};
ContourPlot[
Evaluate@
Table[Simplify@eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]], {a, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}], {w, 0, 12}, {e, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, "\[CurlyEpsilon]"}), RotateLabel -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}, LegendLabel -> "s"], {.7, .4}]]
```

I was able to successfully produce this plot:

[image]

Now I would like to add a tangent line to each curve as follows:

[image]

where the tangent lines and the dots are what I manually added using Microsoft Word. To produce this, I tried the following code:

```
n = 1;
eqns[i_, b_] = {D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == 
D[1 - e, 
  e] ((-(((a (-1 + e) - i - (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
           e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(
            b - 1)))) w))) - (-(((a (-1 + e - i) - (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
           e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (
        n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
        1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))), 0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, w >= 0, 0 <= b <= 1};
cp = ContourPlot[
Evaluate@
Table[Simplify@
  eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]], {a, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
   0.8, 0.9, 1}}], {w, 0, 8}, {e, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
MaxRecursion -> 4, 
FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, "\[CurlyEpsilon]"}), RotateLabel -> False, 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 
   1}, LegendLabel -> "s"], {.7, .4}]];

myEQ = D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == D[1 - e, 
 e] ((-(((a (-1 + e) - i - (
       n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
       1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
          e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (
       n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
       1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w))) - (-(((a (-1 +
           e - i) - (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
       1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
          e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (
       n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(
       1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w))));

Block[{n = 1, i = 1/10, b = 7/10, a = 1/2}, {#, Dt[#, w]} &@
   myEQ] /. {e -> e[w]} /. {e'[w] -> e[w]/w} /. {e[w] -> e} // 
Simplify; icEQ = % /. Equal -> Subtract // Simplify;
icSOL = NSolve[icEQ == 0 && 0 < e < 1 && 0 < w < 2, {e, w}]
(*{{e->0.577473,w->1.6782}}*)

{e\[FivePointedStar], w\[FivePointedStar]} = 
NDSolveValue[{ode = 
Solve[Block[{n = 1, i = 1/10, b = 7/10}, 
   D[{myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {e, w} . 
        D[myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {{e, w}}]} /. {w -> w[a], 
       e -> e[a]}, a] == 0], {e'[a], w'[a]}] /. Rule -> Equal, 
e[1/2] == (e /. First@icSOL), w[1/2] == (w /. First@icSOL)}, {e, w}, {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1}]

Show[cp, Graphics[{PointSize@Medium, 
Point[Table[{w\[FivePointedStar][a], e\[FivePointedStar][a]}, {a, 
   0.1, 0.9, 0.1}]], Opacity[0.3], 
Line[Table[{{0, 0}, {8, 
    8 e\[FivePointedStar][a]/w\[FivePointedStar][a]}}, {a, 0.1, 1,
    0.1}]]}], 
ParametricPlot[{w\[FivePointedStar][a], e\[FivePointedStar][a]}, 
Evaluate@Flatten@{a, e\[FivePointedStar]["Domain"]}, 
PlotStyle -> Magenta, PlotRange -> All], Axes -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 1}}] /. {0.7`, 0.4`} -> {0.88`, 0.4`}
```

which yielded errors. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `myEQ` in the other answer was the equation part of `eqns[i, b]`. That problem has a different equation than this problem. So obviously, `myEQ` has to be updated for this problem.

Secondly, `NSolve`, which solves for the initial condition usually needs some bounds on the variables or you get many real and complex solutions. Those bounds from the previous problem need to be updated for the present problem.

Third, there's copy-pasting bug: When I copy what are supposed to be two separate input lines from the OP above, they are pasted as one line. Since the second line has a `%`, this messes things up. I replaced `%` by a variable.

Finally, getting legends to be placed and formatted as desired is a PIA, IMO. But many formatting problems are.

```
n = 1;
eqns[i_, 
   b_] = {D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] == 
    D[1 - e, 
      e] ((-(((a (-1 + e) - 
               i - (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                  n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
                  e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + 
               i + (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                  n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 
                    1)))) w))) - (-(((a (-1 + e - 
                  i) - (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                  n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) (1 + (-1 + 
                  e) w^2))/((-1 + e) i (1 - e + 
               i + (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - 
                  n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))), 
   0 <= i <= 1, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, w >= 0, 0 <= b <= 1};
cp = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Simplify@
      eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]], {a, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
       0.8, 0.9, 1}}], {w, 0, 8}, {e, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, "\[CurlyEpsilon]"}), 
   RotateLabel -> False, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 
       1}, LegendLabel -> "s"], {2/E, .4}]];

myEQ = First@eqns[i, b];

icEQ = Block[{n = 1, i = 1/10, b = 7/10, a = 1/2}, {#, Dt[#, w]} &@
        myEQ] /. {e -> e[w]} /. {e'[w] -> e[w]/w} /. {e[w] -> e} // 
   Simplify;
icEQ = icEQ /. Equal -> Subtract // Simplify;
icSOL = NSolve[icEQ == 0 && 0 < e < 1 && w > 0, {e, w}]
(*{{e->0.577473,w->1.6782}} <-- N.B.: Answer from the OTHER problem *)
(*  {{e -> 0.631395, w -> 3.1184}}  *)

{e\[FivePointedStar], w\[FivePointedStar]} = 
 NDSolveValue[{ode = 
    Solve[Block[{n = 1, i = 1/10, b = 7/10}, 
       D[{myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {e, w} . 
            D[myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {{e, w}}]} /. {w -> w[a], 
           e -> e[a]}, a] == 0], {e'[a], w'[a]}] /. Rule -> Equal, 
   e[1/2] == (e /. First@icSOL), w[1/2] == (w /. First@icSOL)},
  {e, w}, {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1 - Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon}];

Show[cp, 
  Graphics[{PointSize@Medium, 
    Point[Table[{w\[FivePointedStar][a], e\[FivePointedStar][a]}, {a, 
       0.1, 0.9, 0.1}]], Opacity[0.3], 
    Line[Table[{{0, 0}, {8, 
        8 e\[FivePointedStar][a]/w\[FivePointedStar][a]}}, {a, 0.1, 1,
        0.1}]]}], 
  ParametricPlot[{w\[FivePointedStar][a], e\[FivePointedStar][a]}, 
   Evaluate@Flatten@{a, e\[FivePointedStar]["Domain"]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Magenta, PlotRange -> All], Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 1}}] /.
 (* I hate legends. Betting on {2/E, 0.4} appearing only in Legend[] *)
  {2/E, 0.4} -> {0.8, 0.3}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
cp = ContourPlot[Evaluate @
     Table[Simplify @ eqns[1/10, 7/10][[1]], {a, Rest @ Subdivide[10]}],
   {w, 0, 12}, {e, 0, 1},
   PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4,
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {w, "ε"}), 
   RotateLabel -> False, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[N@Rest@Subdivide[10], 
      LegendLabel -> "s"], {.7, .4}]];
```

**Update:**

A variation on [Ulrich Neumann's much simpler method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288495/125):

```
tangencyDotsAndLines = Cases[Normal @ cp, 
  {d___, Line[x_]} :> 
    With[{xy = First @ MaximalBy[Apply @ ArcTan] @ x}, 
     {PointSize @ Large, Point @ {0, 0}, d, 
     AbsoluteThickness[1/2], Point @ xy, InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, xy}]}], 
  All];

Show[cp, Epilog -> tangencyDotsAndLines]
```

[image]

**Original (Rube Goldberg) approach:**

Construct [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html)s from the coordinates of contour lines:

```
ClearAll[bSplineFunctions, meshFunctions, tangencyPrimitives]

bSplineFunctions = Cases[Normal @ cp[[1]], Line[x_] :> BSplineFunction[x], All];

meshFunctions = Table[With[{f = f}, 
   Function[{x, y, t}, Det[{{x, y}, f' @ t}]]], {f, bSplineFunctions}];
```

We use `bSplineFunctions` and `meshFunctions` with `ParametricPlot` using the option `MeshFunctions` to identify the points tangent to a ray from the origin:

```
tangencyPrimitives = DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[Normal @
  ParametricPlot[# @ t, {t, 10^-5, 1 - 10^-5}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#2}, 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, 
    PlotStyle -> #3, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize @ Large, AbsoluteThickness[1/2]]], 
  {d___, {Point[x_]}} :> {d, Point[x], InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, x}]}, All] &;


epilog = MapThread[tangencyPrimitives] @ 
  {bSplineFunctions, 
   meshFunctions, 
   ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ bSplineFunctions]};


Show[cp, Epilog -> {epilog, PointSize @ Large, Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help! May I ask some follow-up questions? 1) How do I make the tangent lines as dotted, or dashed lines? 2) How do I remove the black dot at the origin? 3) How do I make the dots at the tangent points smaller?

Comment: replace  `{PointSize @ Large, Point @ {0, 0}, d,     AbsoluteThickness[1/2], Point @ xy, InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, xy}]}` with `{PointSize@Medium, d, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1/2], Point@xy,  InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, xy}]}` in the definition of `tangencyDotsAndLines`

Comment: it worked, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @kglr Thanks for including my solution approach! I still wonder why the spline method shows such good results although the underlying signal (examplary ` Plot[   Det[ {bSplineFunctions [[3]] [t], 
   bSplineFunctions [[3]]'[t] }]   , {t, 0, 1} ]` ) is so noisy.

Comment: @kglr, may I ask one more question? In the legend, how do you remove $s=1$? I would like to show $s$ from 0.1 to 0.9 in the legend.

Comment: try `LineLegend[N@Rest@Most@Subdivide[10], LegendLabel -> "s"]`?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a little bit simpler approach taking `cp=ContourPlot[...]( see kglr's answer)`  as start.
This approach doesn't need to know the underlying equations, it only uses the points plotted in `ContourPlot`

```
pts = pic[[1, 1]][[1, 1]]  ;
lines = Cases[pic, Line[p_] :> pts[[p]], -1] ; (* all lines *)

pt = Table[ SortBy[lin, Apply[ArcTan, # ] & ][[-1]], {lin, lines}]
Show[{cp, Graphics[Map[{InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, # ], Point[#]} &, pt]]}]
```

[image]