# Plotting solutions to an equation for varying parameter value produces empty graphs

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Consider an objective function

```
v = ((i + lambda) Uem - (-1 + e) Uun)/(i (1 - e + i + lambda))
```

where

```
n = 1; beta = 0.6; W = 60; i=0.05;
L = (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda = ((1 - e) n L)/(1 - e n L);
Uem = w - 1/(w (1 - e));
b[e_] := b /. Solve[a W (1 + i)^(1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda - 1)- b \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(lambda\)] - 1\)]\(\((1 + i)\)^j\)\) == b + a W, b][[1]];
Uun = b[e] - 1/b[e];
```

with the conditions of $0\leq e \leq 1$ and $U_{em} > U_{un}$.

I would like to do some plotting by taking the following steps.

Step 1: Find `e` that maximizes `v` which will be yielded as a function of `w` with the parameter `a`, i.e., $e = f(w; a)$.

I plotted the `f` function for different values of `a =` ${0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9}$  using the following code:

```
brf[a_, w_] = ArgMax[{v, e >= 0, e <= 1, Uem > Uun}, e];
Plot[{brf[0.1, w] Boole[0.2 <= w <= 6], brf[0.2, w] Boole[0.5 <= w <= 6], brf[0.3, w] Boole[0.8 <= w <= 6], brf[0.4, w] Boole[1.1 <= w <= 6], brf[0.5, w] Boole[1.4 <= w <= 6], brf[0.6, w] Boole[1.7 <= w <= 6], brf[0.7, w] Boole[2 <= w <= 6], brf[0.8, w] Boole[2.3 <= w <= 6], brf[0.9, w] Boole[2.6 <= w <= 6]}, {w, 0, 6}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Table[a, {a, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}], LegendLabel -> a]]
```

which produces
[image]

Step 2: Find `e` and `w` as the solution of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\frac{e}{w}$ for varying values of `a`$\in [0,1]$. Graphically, this is equivalent to finding in the graph below the tangent point of a curve where a ray from the origin (straight dotted line) cross. (I produced this graph by manually adding the rays to the graph above.)

[image]

Step 3: Plot each of `e` and `w` of the tangent points against `a`$\in [0,1]$ on the x-axis.

The code for is:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 1; beta = 0.6; W = 60;
L = (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda = ((1 - e) n L)/(1 - e n L);
Uem = w - 1/(w (1 - e));
b[e_] := b /. Solve[a^2 W (1 + i)^(1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda -1) - b \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(lambda\)] - 1\)]\(\((1 + i)\)^j\)\) ==b + a^2 W, b][[1]];
Uun = b[e] - 1/b[e];
v = ((i + lambda) Uem - (-1 + e) Uun)/(i (1 - e + i + lambda));
f[w_, a_, i_] = ArgMax[{v, e >= 0, e <= 1, Uem > Uun}, e];
With[{i = 5/100}, sol[a_] := sol[a] = FindRoot[D[f[w, a, i], w] == e/w, {{e, 0.5}, {w, 0.5}}]; {estar[a_], wstar[a_]} := {e /. sol[a], w /. sol[a]}; estarplot = Plot[estar[a], {a, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, SuperStar[\[CurlyEpsilon]]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]; wstarplot = Plot[wstar[a], {a, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, SuperStar[w]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}];]
e = estarplot;
w = wstarplot;
Style[Row[{e, w}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {0.6, 0.6}]
```

And I get empty graphs along with a list of error messages as follows. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Edit: As Daniel Huber's answer below suggests, it seems the problem is related to `FindRoot` where `w` gets replaced by a number but I use `w` as a variable for differentiation. But consider the following code, which is almost the same method applied to a different objective function.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[e_, w_, a_, b_, i_, n_] =  D[w - 1/((1 - e) w), e] - D[1 - e, e] ((-((-a (i + (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e)^2 w - a (-1 + e) (i + (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w))) - (-((-a (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1))) + (-1 + a^2) (-1 + e) (-1 + e - i) w - a (-1 + e) (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1))) w^2)/(a (-1 + e) i (1 - e + i + (n (1 - e) (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))/(1 - n e (1/(b (a e)^(b)))^(1/(b - 1)))) w)))); 
With[{i = 1/10, b = 7/10, n = 1}, sol[a_] := sol[a] = FindRoot[{f[e, w, a, b, i, n] == 0, e D[f[e, w, a, b, i, n], e] + w D[f[e, w, a, b, i, n], w] == 0}, {{e, 0.5}, {w, 0.5}}]; {estar[a_], wstar[a_]} := {e /. sol[a], w /. sol[a]}; 
estarplot = Plot[estar[a], {a, 0.1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {a, SuperStar[e]}];
wstarplot = Plot[wstar[a], {a, 0.1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {a,SuperStar[w]}];]
estarplot
wstarplot
```

In this code, the issue raised by Dainel Huber does not emerge but yields plots nicely. Why is this so? What's the difference? In any case, does this mean that the issue is not what Daniel Huber mentioned?

Comment: Testing your functions with a few typical values may help you debug this code.  For example, `f[.5,.5,.5,5/100]` generates error messages.  I would check that the functions `b[e]` and `f[...]` are working properly for several values of the parameters before trying to use the functions in plots or elsewhere.

Comment: ` FindRoot[D[f[e, w, 1, i], w] == e/w, {{e, 0.5}, {w, 0.5}}]`  "e" in f[e...] should be a variable not a number.

Comment: @LouisB, thanks for your comment. I already checked and confirmed that the functions `b[e]` and `f[...]` work. I edit the post to add this. Can you please verify? Thanks much!

Comment: @DanielHuber, thanks for your comment! But isn't `e` in `f[e...]` already a variable, not a number?

Comment: With the revised function and stated parameters I get a plot similar to the one in the question.  When I evaluate `f[5]`, I get 0.584, which says there is a peak in $v$ at $(e,w)=(0.584,5)$.  But, when I evaluate `Plot[v /. w -> 5, {e, .25, .75}]` I don't see a peak.  No peak in `Plot3D[v, {e, .15, .95}, {w, 3, 12}]` either.  I suspect `Maximize` is returning a value on the boundary, but I haven't pursued it.  By the way, you don't need to `Solve` to find $b$.  Just push the symbols around a little to get $b=...$.

Comment: @LouiB, thanks for the catch. But with the initial function `f[...]`, with `e_` removed,  when I evaluate `f[5, 0.9, 0.05]`, I get 0.885, which says there is a peak in $v$ at $(e,w)=(0.885,5)$. And when I evaluate `Plot[v /. { w -> 5, a -> 0.9, i -> 0.05}, {e, 0, 0.95}]`, I do see a peak.

Comment: @LouisB, one more question: Can you please explain a little more about how to get $b$ in a simpler way without `Solve`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interpolating function to simplify and speed-up the code:

```
B[a_] := B[a] = Interpolation[Table[{w, brf[a, w]}, {w, 3 a - .1, 6, .2}] // Quiet]
```

Then, the slope is determined by

```
wc[a_] := FindRoot[B[a]'[wc] wc == B[a][wc], {wc, 0.4 + 4.1 a}][[1, 2]]
```

such that

```
Show[
    Plot[Evaluate@Table[B[a][w] Boole[3 a - .1 < w], {a, .1, .9, .1}], {w, 0, 6}] // Quiet,
    Plot[Evaluate@Table[B[a]'[wc[a]] w, {a, .1, .9, .1}], {w, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
]
```

which produces

[image]

--

The last step, if I understood correctly, is to plot $w_c(a)$ and $f(w_c(a))$ as a function of $a$. This is simple to do:

```
Table[{a, wc[a]}, {a, .1, .9, .05}] // ListPlot
Table[{a, B[a][wc[a]]}, {a, .1, .9, .05}] // ListPlot
```

which produces

[image]

and

[image]

You can clearly see the phase transition around $a~\sim0.21$.

Comment: Thanks! I have three questions: 1) Do you know why the curves in your plot look different from those in mine? They are not fully convex towards the left end. 2) What are `3 a-.1` and `0.4+4.1 a`? 3) What is the `wc[a_]` function and what is the meaning of the equation in `FindRoot[...]`?

Comment: @ppp 1) the function is not analytic at the bottom so the curving up is an artifact of the interpolation I am using. It is just numerical error. You can reduce it by adding more points, the code will run more slowly though. The rest of the curve is unaffected. 2) Just some parameters that I found work best. For example `3a-.1` is just your choice of lower bound on the `Boole`s in your own code, `.2,.5,.8,...` for `a=.1,.2,.3,...`. 3) `wc` is the critical `w`, i.e., the point where $f'(w_c)=e/w_c$. The eq inside `FindRoot` is just this equation, $w_c$ is the point where the line meets the curve

Comment: Thanks very much for the kind explanation. In fact, the ultimate goal of my post was to find the answer to Step 3. May I ask for your help on Step 3? Additionally, may I ask some follow-up questions on your explanation? 1) Is there a way to use the curves as they are without artifacts so that the bottoms look the same? 2) It seems `B[a][wc]` corresponds to the $f$ function, right? I'm asking this since I haven't seen a function code in Mathematica that has two square parenthesis, i.e. `[][]`.

Comment: @ppp 1) There are artifacts in your graph too. It is possible to reduce the error by increasing the number of points before interpolating (namely, replace the `.2` inside `{w, 3 a - .1, 6, .2}` by a smaller number), but it slows down the computation. Increase the number of points as much as you want, and as much as your patience allows. 2) yes, `B` is the same as $f$, the double bracket is syntactic sugar, formally equivalent to `B[a, w]`.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying .1 and it is still running for a while as you warned. In the meantime, may I ask for your help once more on Step 3? That was the main part of my question in the post and what I was ultimately trying to get help for. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @ppp Sure, what do you want to know about step 3?

Comment: As explained in the post, Step 3 (my final goal) is to plot each of $e$ and $w$ from the tangent points in the graph against $a \in [0,1]$. The code I tried can be found in the post as well. Many thanks, in advance!

Comment: @ppp I see. I'll write some code for that later today.

Comment: @ppp See update.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently running the code but it is taking very long... In the meantime, is there a way to get a smooth line plot instead of dotted ones?

Comment: @ppp Add `Joined -> True` to `ListPlot[...]`. [Result](https://imgur.com/4cxJyuh).

Comment: Strange but the code has been running for 4 fours now and it's still running. It seems you are getting the output faster? Just in case, this is the code I'm running https://pastebin.com/raw/zS2U23ej

Comment: @ppp Works for me, used your pastebin and it returned the expected output in 5min or so.

Comment: Strange... I tried again and it's running for an hour now and it is generating some error message while running as follows: https://imgur.com/kcTgUbj

Comment: Now it is five hours the code is running. Do you any clue what might be causing this?

Comment: @ppp Works fine on my laptop, see https://i.imgur.com/eXn7NeO.png Did you try on a fresh kernel? What version are you using? Can you run the code line by line and let me know which specific part makes it hang?

Comment: I'm trying with "fresh kernel" following your suggestion. But let me first accept your answer since the deadline is approaching. Thank you so much for taking time to help with all this! I hope the fresh kernel works.

Comment: I tried fresh kernel and it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sol[0.1]
```

and you get

```
General::ivar: 0.5` is not a valid variable.
```

[image]

Now change the limit of w in FindRoot to 0.4:

```
 FindRoot[D[f[e, w, a, i], w] == e/w, {{e, 0.5}, {w, 0.4}}]
```

and you get:

```
General::ivar: 0.4` is not a valid variable.
```

Therefore, the error is that w get replaced by a number, but you use w as a variable for differentiation.

The solution is to use another variable e.g. ww for differentiation and afterwards replace ww by w.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I think I could use ww for differentiation, i.e. to replace w with ww in `f[]` and `f[]=e/w`, but I'm not sure how to replace it by w afterwards. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: `/. ww->w` or in long form: ReplaceAll

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry but I'm struggling with how to incorporate ww and replacing it to w afterwards as you suggested. May I ask for some more details how to include these into my code? I really appreciate it!

Comment: By rewriting your code, I just saw an additional error. `f` does not depend on `w`. Therefore, you can not take the derivative of `f` relative to `w`. Neither does `f `  depend on `i `, but this should not give an error.

Comment: If I run `v` as defined in the code, I get a long output of `v` as a very complicated function of `e`, `w`, `a`, and `i`. Then, if we find `e` that maximizes `v`, wouldn't I get that `e` as a function of `w`, `a`, and `i`?

Comment: Daniel, in relation to your answer, I have added some comments as an edit towards the end of my post. Can you please take a look at it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice solution. Now the derivatives are done, before "e" has a numerical value.

Comment: Daniel, it's not that I found the solution. I just showed that probably the problem lies elsewhere than what you mentioned by showing that the same type of code works with a different objective function. To clarify, I rephrased the edit part.

Comment: Now the derivative is done in the statement: `f[e_, w_, a_, b_, i_, n_] = ...`where "e" is a symbol without a  numerical value. Before the derivative was done in `FindRoot[D[f[w, a, i], w] == e/w,  ....`where "w" already had a numerical value.

Comment: Daniel, in the edit, if you look carefully, the derivative is also done in `FindRoot[]`. Therein, there are two equations, and the derivative is done in the second equation, no? Thanks for taking time to help. Very much appreciated!