# Why are the plot curves bumpy rather than smooth?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I'm expecting plot curves to be smooth but the results are bumpy. Here is my code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
par = {n -> 1, beta -> 6/10, W -> 60};
L = (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda = ((1 - e) n L)/(1 - e n L);
Uem = w - 1/(w (1 - e));
b[e_] := (a W ((1 + i)^(1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda )-1))/(\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), FractionBox[\(1\), \(lambda\)]]\(\((1 + i)\)^j\)\));
Uun = b[e] - 1/b[e];
v = ((i + lambda) Uem - (-1 + e) Uun)/(i (1 - e + i + lambda));
f[e_, w_, a_, i_] = D[v, e] /. par;
int = Hold[With[{i = 5/100}, sol[a_] := sol[a] = FindRoot[{f[e, w, a, i] == 0, e D[f[e, w, a, i], e] + w D[f[e, w, a, i], w] == 0}, {{e, 0.5, 0.001, 0.999}, {w, 0.5, 0.001, 50}}]; {estar[a_], wstar[a_]} := {e /. sol[a], w /. sol[a]};
estarplot = Plot[estar[a], {a, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, SuperStar[\[CurlyEpsilon]]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
wstarplot = Plot[wstar[a], {a, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, SuperStar[w]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 4}}];]];
rel = ReleaseHold[int /. par];
Rationalize[Chop[rel] /. par] // FullSimplify
e = estarplot;
w = wstarplot;
Style[Row[{e, w}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {0.6, 0.6}]
```

and the output is as follows:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out why the plots are not in smooth line but bumpy. Can anyone help please?
By the way, $s$ in the plot is `a` in the code; and the range for the key variables and parameters are as follows: `0<e<1`, `w > 0`, and `0<=a<=1` (which is for $s$).

**Edit**: I tried adding `MaxRecursion->0` to each `Plot[]` and obtain this:

[image]

which is less bumpy than before but is still not fully smooth. I found that increasing the value for `MaxRecursion` makes the plots more bumpy.

Comment: Looks like your function is numerically unstable due to precision losses. So small changes in the value of the variable a give large changes in the function estar[a]. Plot attempts to follow that variation with tiny steps. If it's too complicated to find a stable expression for your function, a work around is to evaluate star[a] at some discrete set of a values where you don't get error messages, and use ListLinePlot to connect those values as a curve.

Comment: @tad, thanks for the comments! Can you please help how to do that?

Comment: I suspect that the ODE method outlined by MichaelE2 on your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287287/) will do better at avoiding these types of errors than the method I suggested to you.

Answer (score 1):

The function definition appears to be numerically unstable. Best would be to identify the cause of the problem and modify your function to avoid, if possible.  E.g., using higher precision numbers or better starting estimates in FindRoot.

A work around is to evaluate your function at a list of values that don't give warning messages, and use ListLinePlot.

For example:

```
Table[{a, estar[a]}, {a, 0.1, 1, .1}]
```

which gives

```
{{0.1, 0.485413}, {0.2, 0.445871}, {0.3, 0.400952}, {0.4, 0.457175}, {0.5, 0.460944}, {0.6, 0.471048}, {0.7, 0.497545}, {0.8, 0.526322}, {0.9, 0.549633}, {1., 0.567227}}
```

then plot, e.g.,

```
ListLinePlot[%, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

to get a plot with markers showing the values used.
[image]

You can try other values of the variable a to get additional points, avoiding any that give warnings (which suggest the evaluation isn't able to find a good solution).

For this to work as separate input lines in a notebook, I had to define the function estar[a]. Your code wraps its definition in Hold and then you use ReleaseHold. I don't think that's necessary.