Plot the solution of a differential equation
Consider:
$$\frac{1}{(1-e)^2 w}=v-z$$
where $v=f(e,i,L,W,a,n)$, $z=g(e,i,L,W,a,w,n)$, and $L = h(e,w,a,b)$ are given functions.
From the above equation, $e$ can be derived as a function of $w$ along with the other parameters, i.e., $e=e(w;\dots)$. Using the latter, we can consider the following differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial e}{\partial w}=\frac{e}{w}$$
I would like find $e$ and $w$ that satisfies the above differential equation. Obviously, both $e$ and $w$ will come out as a function of $a$ along with the other parameters.
Finally, I would like to create four separate plots for $e$, $w$, $\frac{e}{w}$, and $\frac{ae}{w}$ each of them against $a\in [0,1]$ with the parameter values of $n=1$, $W=60$, $i=0.1$, and $b=0.6$.
By closely referring to Michael E2's answer to this post, I tried to come up with the following code:
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 1; W = 60;
L = (w/(b (a e)^b))^(1/(b - 1));
v = -(((-1 + e - i) (-i + (-1 + e + e i) L n) (1/((-1 + e) (-1 + e - i) w) + w/(-1 + e - i) + ((-1 + e) (1 - e L n) (-(1 + i)^2 (-1 + (1 + i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n)))^2 + a^2 i^2 (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n)))^2 W^2))/(a i (1 + i) (1 - e + i) (1 - (1 + i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n))) (1 - (1 + i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n))) (i - (-1 + e + e i) L n) W)))/(i (1 + i + L n + e (-1 + (-2 + e - i) L n))));
z = -((a i (1 + i)^((1 + e)/(1 - e)) (-1 + (1 + i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n))) (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n))) L n W + a (-1 + e) i (1 + i)^((1 + e)/(1 - e)) (-1 + (1 + i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n))) (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n))) L n w^2 W + (-1 + e - i) (1 + i)^(-((2 e)/(-1 + e))) (-1 + e L n) w (1 + 2 i + i^2 - a^2 i^2 W^2 - 2 (1 + i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n)) ((1 + i)^(2 + 1/(-1 + e)) - a^2 i^2 W^2) + (1 + i)^(2 + 2/(L n - e L n)) ((1 + i)^((2 e)/(-1 + e)) -a^2 i^2 W^2)))/(a i^2 (1 + i) ((1 + i)^(e/(1 - e)) - (1 + i)^(1/(L n - e L n))) ((1 + i)^(e/(1 - e)) - (1 + i)^((1 + L n)/(L n - e L n))) (1 + i + L n + e (-1 + (-2 + e - i) L n)) w W));

myEQ = 1/((1 - e)^2 w) == v - z;

Block[{n = 1, W = 60, i = 1/10, b = 6/10, a = 1/2}, {#, Dt[#, w]} &@myEQ] /. {e -> e[w]} /. {e'[w] -> e[w]/w} /. {e[w] -> e} // Simplify; 
icEQ = % /. Equal -> Subtract // Simplify;
icSOL = NSolve[icEQ == 0 && 0 < e < 1 && w > 0, {e, w}]

{e, w} = NDSolveValue[{ode = Solve[Block[{n = 1, W = 60, i = 1/10, b = 6/10}, D[{myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {e, w} . D[myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {{e, w}}]} /. {w -> w[a], e -> e[a]}, a] == 0], {e'[a], w'[a]}] /. Rule -> Equal, e[1/2] == (e /. First@icSOL), w[1/2] == (w /. First@icSOL)}, {e, w}, {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1}]

ListLinePlot[e, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, "e"}]
ListLinePlot[w, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, "w"}]

The code runs forever. Also, I failed to come up with a code that creates the four separate plots. By the way, the code is exactly the same as Michael E2's except that the equation in MyEQ is now a more complicated one with v, z, and L. Since Michael E2's code with the original MyEQ equation works well, I don't think there is an error in the code itself.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

You assign a value to b but you don't use that variable. Is b actually beta?

@BobHanlon, yes, you are correct. I have edited accordingly and now they are all in b consistently. Thanks!

You still have beta in your code.  But even if I replace it with b your Block construct is hanging apparently because of the Simplify.  Removing the Simplify it quickly completes.  Next, removing Simplify on icEQ runs quickly but then ICSOL starts hanging.

Another suggestion:  IcEQ as written above is in brackets as in {icEQ}. Not sure that's a construct error.  However, if I remove the bracket and pick a value of e and then use FindRoot to solve w at 25 digits of precision I can get a solution as in:  FindRoot[( icEQ[[1]] == 0 /. e -> 1/5), {w, 1/2},   WorkingPrecision -> 25]  returning {e,w)={1/5, 3.504}.  If this is usable, you could generate a table of such FindRoots for your needs.

@josh, thanks for your comments. Yes, beta is now all corrected to b. I'm not sure if I'm following what you are saying. Would it be possible for you to show me with code? Thanks so much!

Afraid I can't easily do that as I don't want to post a partial answer.  Let theBlock be the result of the Block command above without Simplify.  Then to find one set of initial conditions, rather than use NSolve above, simply choose a value of e say $1/5$ then use FindRoot to find $w$ via icEQ = theBlock /. Equal -> Subtract; wVal = w /.    FindRoot[( icEQ[[1]] == 0 /. e -> 1/5), {w, 1/2},     WorkingPrecision -> 25]   Would also be easier to scale-down definition of v,z, and L just to get NDSolve working then add to problem in my opinion.

@josh, Thanks for your comments. I tried to follow your comments but failed. May I ask if you could provide an answer with full code? I would really appreciate that. Thank you so much for your help.

@ppp It is not clear from your code what is the domain of parameter a ?

@Alex Trounev,  0<=a<=1.

@ppp How you know that there exists real solution?

@AlexTrounev, you are correct, I haven't seriously checked whether there exists real solution. Any suggestions to verify this? Thank you so much.

@ppp Maybe first we need to check range of parameters a, b, i, n, W where real solution exists?

@ppp:  I couldn't provide an answer because I don't understand your DE as well as some other issues and I suspect others are confused as well -- for example Dt is differentiating all symbols with respect to `w' unless you explicitly identify the constants.
If it stands unsolved for a time, would you want me to  post what I think is a simpler equivalent problem which may or may not be what you want but may help stimulate questions and suggestions towards a solution to your problem?

@josh, 1) I found some grave typoes in the last three lines of the code, which I corrected.
2) Can you please take a look at this original code by Michael E2: https://pastebin.com/raw/vyZpupN5 with simpler v and z. This code works well producing exactly the types of plots I'm looking for. Not sure why one works but not the other when the two codes are exactly the same with the only difference in v and z. Maybe this code provides answers to the questions you raised? Thank you so much!

@josh, to better understanding my DE, my original question in the linked post would be clarifying. Here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287287/solving-implicit-function-numerically-and-plotting-the-solution-against-a-parame

@ppp:  Ok, already looked at it.  Not helpful to me.  Really some brilliant people in here, never have I saw such beautiful work with DEs then this place.  They'll get to it.  Interesting problem.

We can solve this problem as an optimization problem as follows. First note, that we don't know upfront are there real solutions for a given parameters or not. Therefore we need to compute a global minimum for myEQ to define a real solution. Differential equation $\frac{\partial e}{\partial w}=\frac{e}{w}$ can be integrated in general form as $w=c e$, where c is arbitrary constant. The global minimum is defined in a form
L = (w/(b (a e)^b))^(1/(b - 1));
v = -(((-1 + e - 
         i) (-i + (-1 + e + e i) L n) (1/((-1 + e) (-1 + e - i) w) + 
         w/(-1 + e - 
            i) + ((-1 + e) (1 - 
              e L n) (-(1 + 
                   i)^2 (-1 + (1 + i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n)))^2 +
               a^2 i^2 (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 
                    1/(L n - e L n)))^2 W^2))/(a i (1 + i) (1 - e + 
              i) (1 - (1 + i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n))) (1 - (1 + 
                 i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n))) (i - (-1 + e + 
                 e i) L n) W)))/(i (1 + i + L n + 
         e (-1 + (-2 + e - i) L n))));
z = -((a i (1 + 
           i)^((1 + e)/(1 - e)) (-1 + (1 + 
             i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n))) (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 
             1/(L n - e L n))) L n W + 
       a (-1 + e) i (1 + 
           i)^((1 + e)/(1 - e)) (-1 + (1 + 
             i)^((1 - e L n)/(L n - e L n))) (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 
             1/(L n - e L n))) L n w^2 W + (-1 + e - 
          i) (1 + i)^(-((2 e)/(-1 + e))) (-1 + e L n) w (1 + 2 i + 
          i^2 - a^2 i^2 W^2 - 
          2 (1 + i)^(1 + 1/(L n - e L n)) ((1 + i)^(2 + 1/(-1 + e)) - 
             a^2 i^2 W^2) + (1 + i)^(2 + 
              2/(L n - e L n)) ((1 + i)^((2 e)/(-1 + e)) - 
             a^2 i^2 W^2)))/(a i^2 (1 + 
         i) ((1 + i)^(e/(1 - e)) - (1 + i)^(1/(L n - e L n))) ((1 + 
            i)^(e/(1 - e)) - (1 + i)^((1 + L n)/(L n - e L n))) (1 + 
         i + L n + e (-1 + (-2 + e - i) L n)) w W));

 eq1 = 1/((1 - e)^2 w) - v + z; eq2 = w - c  e; var = {a, e, b, i, n, W, c}; con = {0 < a < 1, 0 < e < 1, 
  0 < c  e < 2, W > 0, i > 0, n > 0, b > 0}; sol = 
 NMinimize[{eq1^2 /. w -> c  e, con}, var]

(*Out[]= {3.05276*10^-21, {a -> 0.12749, e -> 0.131433, b -> 0.154335, 
  i -> 0.170289, n -> 0.183486, W -> 0.19822, c -> 0.193286}}*)

Using this data we can compute also a local minimum, we have
s2 = Drop[sol[[2]], 2]

(*Out[]= {b -> 0.154335, i -> 0.170289, n -> 0.183486, W -> 0.19822, 
 c -> 0.193286}*)
var1 = {a, e}; con1 = {0 < a < 1, 0 < e < 1}; ini1 = 
 Table[{var1[[j]], var1[[j]] /. sol[[2]]}, {j, Length[var1]}]; sol2 = 
 FindMinimum[({eq1^2, con1} /. w -> c  e) /. s2, ini1]

Out[]= {8.26643*10^-18, {a -> 0.417144, e -> 0.497054}}

The way from the global minimum to the local minimum is some curve $e=e(a)$, that we can extract from FindMinimum using StepMonitor
pts = Reap[
    FindMinimum[{eq1^2 /. w -> c  e /. s2, con1}, ini1, 
     StepMonitor :> Sow[{a, e, eq1 /. w -> c  e /. s2}], 
     MaxIterations -> 1000]][[2, 1]];

Finally we can plot pts with contours of expression eq1==0, we have
plot1=ContourPlot[(eq1 /. w -> c  e /. s2) == 
  0, {a, .001, .5}, {e, .01, .99}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[pts[[All, 1 ;; 2]]], Point[pts[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"a", "e"}] 


To plot all other curves we can extract list of points {a,e} from plot1, then construct lists for w and plot it
lst = plot1[[1]][[1]][[1]]; = Transpose[{lst[[All, 1]], c  lst[[All, 2]]}] /. sol[[2]];


ListLinePlot[lstw, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "w"}]


All other functions like w/e=c and a e/w=a/c can be plot as well for this kind of solutions.
Update 1 We can use ContourPlot to visualize solution for a given parameters as follows
n = 1; W = 60; i = 0.1; b = .6;Table[ContourPlot[(eq1 /. w -> c  e) == 0, {a, 
   0.01, .99}, {e, .4, .99}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"c = ", c}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"a", "e"}, PlotPoints -> 100], {c, .02, .22, .05}]


The bottom branch in the picture above can be reproduced with FindRoot as
sol10 = Table[
   Select[Quiet@
     Table[{a, e, Abs[eq1 /. w -> c e]} /. 
       Quiet@FindRoot[(eq1 /. w -> c e) == 0, {e, .9}, 
         Method -> {"Newton", 
           "StepControl" -> 
            "TrustRegion"}], {a, .001, .999, .001}], #[[2]] > 
       0 && #[[2]] < 1 && #[[3]] < 10^-10 &], {c, .02, .22, .05}];

p1 = ListPlot[Table[sol10[[j]][[All, 1 ;; 2]], {j, 5}], 
  PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"c =", c}], {c, .02, .22, .05}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"a", "e"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {.4, 1}}];

sol04 = Table[
   Select[Quiet@
     Table[{a, e, Abs[eq1 /. w -> c e]} /. 
       Quiet@FindRoot[(eq1 /. w -> c e) == 0, {e, .1}, 
         Method -> {"Newton", 
           "StepControl" -> 
            "TrustRegion"}], {a, .001, .999, .001}], #[[2]] > 
       0 && #[[2]] < 1 && #[[3]] < 10^-10 &], {c, .02, .22, .05}];

p2 = ListPlot[Table[sol04[[j]][[All, 1 ;; 2]], {j, 5}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"a", "e"}]; 
Show[p1, p2]


We also can generate 3D plot using code
sol = Select[
   Flatten[Quiet@
     Table[{a, c, e, Abs[eq1 /. w -> c e]} /. 
       Quiet@FindRoot[(eq1 /. w -> c e) == 0, {e, .9}, 
         Method -> {"Newton", 
           "StepControl" -> 
            "TrustRegion"}], {a, .01, .99, .01}, {c, .01, .5, .01}], 
    1], #[[3]] > 0 && #[[3]] < 1 && #[[4]] < 10^-10 &];

sol0 = Select[
   Flatten[Quiet@
     Table[{a, c, e, Abs[eq1 /. w -> c e]} /. 
       Quiet@FindRoot[(eq1 /. w -> c e) == 0, {e, .1}, 
         Method -> {"Newton", 
           "StepControl" -> 
            "TrustRegion"}], {a, .01, .99, .01}, {c, .01, .5, .01}], 
    1], #[[3]] > 0 && #[[3]] < 1 && #[[4]] < 10^-10 &];

ListPointPlot3D[{sol0[[All, 1 ;; 3]], sol[[All, 1 ;; 3]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "c", "e"}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 PlotRange -> All]


Update 2 The original ppp's code could be modified as follows
Clear["Global`*"];
L = (w/(b  (a  e)^b))^(1/(b - 1));
v = -(((-1 + e - 
         i)  (-i + (-1 + e + 
            e  i)  L  n)  (1/((-1 + e)  (-1 + e - i)  w) + 
         w/(-1 + e - 
            i) + ((-1 + e)  (1 - 
              e  L  n)  (-(1 + 
                   i)^2  (-1 + (1 + 
                    i)^((1 - e  L  n)/(L  n - e  L  n)))^2 + 
              a^2  i^2  (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 
                    1/(L  n - e  L  n)))^2  W^2))/(a  i  (1 + i)  (1 -
               e + i)  (1 - (1 + 
                 i)^((1 - e  L  n)/(L  n - e  L  n)))  (1 - (1 + 
                 i)^(1 + 1/(L  n - e  L  n)))  (i - (-1 + e + 
                 e  i)  L  n)  W)))/(i  (1 + i + L  n + 
         e  (-1 + (-2 + e - i)  L  n))));
z = -((a  i  (1 + 
           i)^((1 + e)/(1 - e))  (-1 + (1 + 
             i)^((1 - e  L  n)/(L  n - e  L  n)))  (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 
             1/(L  n - e  L  n)))  L  n  W + 
       a  (-1 + 
          e)  i  (1 + 
           i)^((1 + e)/(1 - e))  (-1 + (1 + 
             i)^((1 - e  L  n)/(L  n - e  L  n)))  (-1 + (1 + i)^(1 + 
             1/(L  n - e  L  n)))  L  n  w^2  W + (-1 + e - 
          i)  (1 + i)^(-((2  e)/(-1 + e)))  (-1 + e  L  n)  w  (1 + 
          2  i + i^2 - a^2  i^2  W^2 - 
          2  (1 + i)^(1 + 
              1/(L  n - e  L  n))  ((1 + i)^(2 + 1/(-1 + e)) - 
             a^2  i^2  W^2) + (1 + i)^(2 + 
              2/(L  n - e  L  n))  ((1 + i)^((2  e)/(-1 + e)) - 
             a^2  i^2  W^2)))/(a  i^2  (1 + 
         i)  ((1 + i)^(e/(1 - e)) - (1 + 
            i)^(1/(L  n - e  L  n)))  ((1 + i)^(e/(1 - e)) - (1 + 
            i)^((1 + L  n)/(L  n - e  L  n)))  (1 + i + L  n + 
         e  (-1 + (-2 + e - i)  L  n))  w  W));



icSOL[x_] := 
 Module[{rule = {n -> 1, W -> 60, i -> 1/10, b -> 6/10, a -> x}}, 
  myEQ = 1/((1 - e)^2  w) - v + z /. {e -> e[w]}; 
  icEQ = D[myEQ, w] /. {e'[w] -> e[w]/w} /. {e[w] -> e};
  s = NMinimize[{icEQ^2 /. rule, {0 < e < 1, 0 < w < 2}}, {e, w}]; s]

(*Compute initial condition*)
icSOL[0.5]

(*Out[]= {2.18427*10^-24, {e -> 0.359048, w -> 0.112498}}*)

ic = {e, w} /. %[[2]];

eqs = Module[{rule = {n -> 1, W -> 60, i -> 1/10, b -> 6/10}}, 
   eq = 1/((1 - e)^2  w) - v + z; 
   rhs = D[{eq, {e, w} . D[eq, {{e, w}}]} /. {w -> w[a], e -> e[a]}, 
     a]; Thread[rhs == {0, 0}] /. rule];

sol = 
 NDSolveValue[{eqs, e[1/2] == ic[[1]], w[1/2] == ic[[2]]}, {e, 
   w}, {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

Note that we have solution for 0<a<0.504197417091105 only. Visualization
{Plot[sol[[1]][a], {a, 0, .5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {a, "e"}],
 Plot[sol[[2]][a], {a, 0, .5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {a, "w"}], 
 Plot[sol[[1]][a]/sol[[2]][a], {a, 0, .5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "e/w"}],
  Plot[a  sol[[1]][a]/sol[[2]][a], {a, 0, .5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"a", "a e/w"}]}



Thanks! Some questions: 1) It seems s2 is a typo? 2) It seems c is considered as a constant parameter just like b, i, W, n. But it is not. It is endogenously determined just like e and w. Maybe I'm misreading your code?

So for point (2) in my above comments, here is a clarification of how c is endogenous in my system: From the first equation in my post, e=e(w; a,i,b,n,W) can be derived, which turns out to be a concave and increasing function in w. Now the (e,w) pair that satisfies the second equation in my post would occur where a linear ray from the origin touches the e=e(w) curve. And c would refer to the slope of the ray. In this context, an increase in a will shift the e=e(w) curve to the right and hence will make the tangent line flatter, i.e. making c smaller.

You can take a look at the first two graphs in the link below and you'll see what I mean. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287287/solving-implicit-function-numerically-and-plotting-the-solution-against-a-parame

One more question: 3) In the first two plots, do you know why the e and w curves are shared in those ways so that we have, say, two values of e for each a and the same for w? And what does those red dots mean on the e curve?

Due to the typo mentioned above, the code starting from the second block doesn't work.

@ppp 1) First code generates optimal solution only. 2) Second code generates solution for different c, and last picture shows this kind of solution. 3) If you suppose that $c=c(a)$ then you need additional equation to compute this function. Another words you need initial condition for differential equation.

All the codes, except for the first one, don't work and produce error messages, according to which it seems it is due to s2. Do you know what it should be replaced?

Regarding the endogeneity of $c$, I understand your point. But strangely, I already obtained two solutions (which yields $c$ endogenously) a while ago to my same problem but with simpler v and z. This is in the link in my previous comment above. I'm trying to see if there is anything wrong in the presentation of my question in this post...

@ppp Sorry, the definition s2 has been added.

Alex, thanks for the fix. But now the code right after the first plot is not working and it produces error messages. At any rate, it seems I may have to create another post that better explains my question where $c$ has to be endogenously determined.

@ppp Fortunately I have debugged your code, so you can compare your solution and my solution above :)

Alex, this looks great, many thanks!! May I ask, so does it mean that we don't have to go through the processes in your initial solution that involves global and local minimum to ensure real solutions? Can I just use your "debugged" solution? The main difference seems to be whether $c$ is exogenous or endogenous?

One more comment: One minor typo in my code 0<w<2 is corrected to w>0, and now your debugged solution yields real values for w even after a=0.504197417091105. Still, for 0.504197417091105<a<1, e doesn't have solutions and w explodes. This result makes me think that my model is not feasible in the first place... Alex, do you know why we have this critical point of a=0.504197417091105??

@ppp Please, see Figure 1 in my answer above. Solution has two branches connecting in critical point. In this regards it could be better to use e as a variable and a[e],w[e] as functions.

Alex, thanks so much for the reply! I'm trying to compare my solution and your 'debugged' solution, for which it is important to additionally plot e/w and a e/w as well. In your solution, which uses Plot, it was easy to produce the two additional plots by plotting sol[[1]][a]/sol[[2]][a] and a sol[[1]][a]/sol[[2]][a]. But I fail with my solution which uses Listlineplot; simply plotting e/w and a e/w won't work. May I ask for your help in producing the two additional plots in my solution?

By the way, as I mentioned earlier, there is still an error in the code for your solution; the code right after the first plot produces error messages. Can you please let me know how to fix it? Thank you so much!

@ppp Sorry I didn't see you questions since you are not mentioned my name.  For plots you are looking for see update to my answer.

Alex, thanks but I was able to produce those plots on my own. My question was to produce the plots using Listlineplot as in my original solution. May I sincerely ask for your help on this? Many thanks!

@ppp This looks like endless story. This is not how MA stackexchange works. Try to limit the scope to one question per post and also accept and upvote answers if you like them. Very often, the quality of answers depends on the quality of questions.

Alex, per yarchik's comment, it seems I have to make a separate post to ask how to create those two additional plots using Listlineplot as in my original code. Then before I accept your answer, can you please help fix the remaining error in your code I mentioned above: the code right after the first plot produces error messages. Thank you!

Alex, I have put my question regarding creating the two additional plots using Listlineplot in a new post here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303923/plotting-functions-of-the-solutions-of-ndsolvevalue. I would truly appreciate your help on this. Thank you so much, Alex!

@ppp It looks like you never read tutorials. :) You can't use ListLinePlot[] with interpolating functions e[a], w[a]. First you should prepare list like 'lst=Table[{a,e[a]}, {a,0,1,.01}] and then use ListLinePlot[lst].

@Alex, thanks for the helpful comment!
