Plotting functions of the solutions of `NDSolveValue`
I'm trying to create plots of the solutions from NDSolveValue. Here is my code:
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 10; W = 100; q = 5/100; b = 6/10;
v = ((-i + (-1 + e + i) n (((a e)^-b w)/b)^(1/(-1 + b))) (w + a q W + 1/((-1 + e) (w + a q W)) - ((-1 + e) (-1 + n (((a e)^-b w)/b)^(1/(-1 + b))) (-1 + a^2 q^2 W^2))/(a q (-i + (-1 + e + i) n (((a e)^-b w)/b)^(1/(-1 + b))) W)))/(i (-1 + e + i (-1 + n (((a e)^-b w)/b)^(1/(-1 + b)))));
z = ((-1 + e - i) (w + a q W) (-1 + a^2 q^2 W^2) + n (((a e)^-b w)/b)^(1/(-1 + b)) ((-1 + e - i) w + a q (e - i + (-1 + e) w^2) W + a^2 (-1 + e + i) q^2 w W^2 + a^3 i q^3 W^3))/(a i q (-1 + e + i (-1 + n (((a e)^-b w)/b)^(1/(-1 + b)))) W (w + a q W));

myEQ = 1/((1 - e)^2 w) == v - z;

Block[{n = 10, W = 100, q = 5/100, i = 5/100, b = 6/10, a = 1/2}, {#, Dt[#, w]} &@myEQ] /. {e -> e[w]} /. {e'[w] -> e[w]/w} /. {e[w] -> e} // Simplify;
icEQ = % /. Equal -> Subtract // Simplify;
icSOL = NSolve[icEQ == 0 && 0 < e < 1 && w > 0, {e, w}]

{e, w} = NDSolveValue[{ode = Solve[Block[{n = 10, W = 100, q = 5/100, i = 5/100, b = 6/10}, D[{myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {e, w} . D[myEQ /. Equal -> Subtract, {{e, w}}]} /. {w -> w[a], e -> e[a]}, a] == 0], {e'[a], w'[a]}] /. Rule -> Equal, e[1/2] == (e /. First@icSOL), w[1/2] == (w /. First@icSOL)}, {e, w}, {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1}]

{ListLinePlot[e, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, "e"}],ListLinePlot[w, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, "w"}]}

which successfully produces plots of e and w against a as follows:

Now, I would like to produce two more plots of e/w and a e/w against a. The code I tried was this:
{ListLinePlot[e/w, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, "e/w"}],ListLinePlot[a e/w, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a, "ae/w"}]}

But it didn't work. Any help please?

Why not use Plot? (P.S. I find including Clear["Global`*"]; rather irritating. Why do you think I would want to clear all of my definitions?)

Hi Michael! In fact, the code here is an exact copy of your code where you used Listlineplot. By the way, I was desperately looking for your help on the following question as the code there is an exact copy of your code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303422/plot-the-solution-of-a-differential-equation. Regarding your P.S., I'm not sure if I'm understanding when you say "clear all of my definitions"?

@ppp It looks like you never read tutorials. :) You can't use ListLinePlot[] with interpolating functions e[a], w[a]. First you should prepare list like 'lst=Table[{a,e[a]}, {a,0,1,.01}] and then use ListLinePlot[lst].

@Alex, thanks for the helpful comment!

ListLinePlot[e] works when e is an InterpolatingFunction[] (IF). It takes the table of steps from the IF and makes a traditional list plot of the data. ListLinePlot[e[a]] does not work; nor does ListLinePlot[e/w], ListLinePlot[2 e] or any other composite expression that is more complicated than a simple IF. In fact, you cannot combine functions, whether IFs or Function[] or Sin, except via expressions like e[a]/w[a], which are not functions. The traditional way to plot expressions is Plot[], not ListLinePlot[]. Each is advantageous in different situations.

Another tip: Overwriting the variables you use in your equations with {e, w} = NDSolveValue[...] is a cruel trick to play on those who would like to help you quickly. My front end has been frozen for at least fifteen minutes now. It really discourages me from helping. Indeed I can't until it unfreezes. Or I kill it and lose whatever I haven't saved. I know you're new to Mma, but take some time to understand the things you're pasting into your code. You have some odd things you should question, like why do you write n = 10 etc. twice. Apparently you pasted it in without thinking.

@MichaelE2, I'm trying to understanding when you say: "Overwriting the variables you use in your equations with {e, w} = NDSolveValue[...] is a cruel trick to play on those who would like to help you quickly." At any rate, thanks for the helpful comments.

It means I can't rerun the code without disaster. I can't analyze the equation and solution because the variables are no longer undefined symbols. As I said, Clear["Global`*"]; is likewise inconvenient, since it clears things I don't want cleared. Normally I just give up on helping in such situations. I don't know if complaining is nicer or ignoring someone seeking help is nicer. The latter is less work usually, but this time I complained. I mean it with kind intentions, but it seems so easy for negative reactions to happen, I usually just skip the whole Q&A.

@MichaelE2, thanks for taking time to clarify. I wasn't sure whether you are referring to the code in this post or the one in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303422/plot-the-solution-of-a-differential-equation. Or maybe both. (By the way, it was the latter for which I was looking for your help. They are different in terms of different expressions of v and z and the code there runs forever.) For a future reference, may I ask how I could have better posed the question with the right code?

This is to illustrate the use of Plot[], which, imo, is the best tool for plotting expression built from interpolating functions. I feel it should be mentioned prominently for visitors who come across the post solutions to the simple task in the title, "Plotting functions of the solutions of NDSolveValue".
Either:
Plot[esol[a]/wsol[a], {a, 0, 1}]
Plot[a  esol[a]/wsol[a], {a, 0, 1}]

Or:
Plot[e[a]/w[a] /. {e -> esol, w -> wsol}, {a, 0, 1}]
Plot[a  e[a]/w[a] /. {e -> esol, w -> wsol}, {a, 0, 1}]

[Of course, you should change the OP's code to set {esol, wsol} = NDSolveValue[...] instead of overwriting the equation variables e and w. ]
One gets with the initial condition {e -> 0.618664, w -> 1.90196}:

For another solution to icEQ, one gets a different plot:

But there seems to be only one solution with 0 < e < 1.

MichaelE2, thanks so much! I got a slightly different output here: https://rb.gy/hh1hp6 where it seems there are two solutions with 0<e<1? My plots look closer to your second pair of plots with e->1.97786, w->1.307. By the way, my four plots are, respectively, e, w, e/w, and a e/w.

One way is to generate e/w and a e/w in table then plot them
data1 = Table[e[a]/w[a], {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1, .01}];
data2 = Table[a*e[a]/w[a], {a, $MachineEpsilon, 1, .01}];


{ListLinePlot[data1, AxesLabel -> {"a", "e/w"}, DataRange -> {0, 1}], 
 ListLinePlot[data2, AxesLabel -> {"a", "a e/w"}, 
  DataRange -> {0, 1}]}



thanks so much!
